# How can I get unordered array of keys from object

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-objects

I have data from backend in my js like this:

```
var list = {
    "6": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "John",
        "age": 31
    },
    "42": {
        "id": 42,
        "name": "Alex",
        "age": 25
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Tim",
        "age": 58
    },
};
```

Then I need to display this data in my angular html template through ngFor directive. But first I have to get an array of object keys:

```
var listKeys= Object.keys(list);
```

Next I can output data in template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of listKeys">
    <p>{{list[item].id}}</p>
    <p>{{list[item].name}}</p>
    <p>{{list[item].age}}</p>
    <hr>
</div>
```

But the problem is that order of my data changed. I have in listKeys next array ["3", "6", "42"]. But **I want to have original order** in that one ["6", "42", "3"]. One of solutions that I have found is make keys as not numeric string. For example:

```
var list = {
    "+6": {...},
    "+42": {...},
    "+3": {...},
};
```

But I don't have access to backend. I need another solution.

---

P.S. The way in which I get data from the backend

```
  getData() {
    this._dataService.getList(this.name, this.age).subscribe(res => {
      this.list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
      this.listKeys = Object.keys(this.list);
    });   
  }
```

Comment: Use an array instead of an object? what does `Object.keys(list)` output ?

Comment: The order of the properties in an object is not guaranteed in JS.

Comment: Object.keys(list) output ["3", "6", "42"] ---
http://plnkr.co/edit/JEe5bMbdPaTqVgY3IuOs?p=info

Comment: You don't need access to the backend, data should always be ordered by the consumer unless it is a subset of bigger data such as paged data etc... Anyway your original `list` object actually is not iterated over in the order you think. See [**Property Traversal Order**](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html) - As mentioned above, to guarantee the order add the items to an array in the order you prefer. Using an object in this case is not correct.

Comment: @Nope ... I assumed the object in `list` was the result of a JSON.parse ... @ironfist, exactly how is the data coming from the backend, and how does the var `list` get defined?

Comment: Are you using JSON.parse at any stage? Or, how are you getting "data from backend"

Comment: @ironfist You do need to ensure that what ever sends you the data does so in the correct structure. I would be surprised if any other consumer of the same call expected "rows" of results to be returned as properties of an object as that would be very much incorrect. Can you please share the code that makes the call and processes the response as that is most likely where the issue lies. That is probably where the `list` array needs to be created to begin with.

Comment: well, at your request, I have added the way in which I get data from the backend in the description of the question

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))` ...  damn, so res is already a javascript object - do you have access to the "raw" JSON?

Comment: I have access to JSON through internal (not public) url. But I do not have the opportunity to form it differently. You can see how it looks here: https://api.myjson.com/bins/uu2nb

Comment: Why do you need to know the original order? It's only in the printed form that there is a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, an object is an unordered collection of properties. As a solution, you could use an array instead of an object:

The first step would be to convert the response from the server to an array in the same order.

```js
// Original JSON string received from API
var jsonString = `{
    "6": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "John",
        "age": 31
    },
    "42": {
        "id": 42,
        "name": "Alex",
        "age": 25
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Tim",
        "age": 58
    }
}`;

// Array of ordered id's
const orderedIds = [];

// Find all id's in the JSON string and push them to the array
const pattern = /"?id"?\: (\d*)/g;
let match;
while (match = pattern.exec(jsonString)) {
 orderedIds.push(parseInt(match[1]));        
}
 
 
// parse the original JSON object
const originalList = JSON.parse(jsonString);


// resulting ordered Array
const result = [];

// Push the object in the array by order
for(x of orderedIds) {
 result.push(originalList[x]);
}

// Log the resulting array
document.getElementById("result").innerText = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

The result will be an array of the objects in the same order as they appeared in the JSON string:

```
result = [
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "John",
        "age": 31
    },
    {
        "id": 42,
        "name": "Alex",
        "age": 25
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Tim",
        "age": 58
    },
];
```

After this you can use it in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of result">
    <p>{{item.id}}</p>
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <p>{{item.age}}</p>
    <hr>
</div>
```

this array does garantee the order of its values.

Comment: But I get the data as an object from the server. Or should I transform an object into an array?

Comment: problem with transforming into an array - if done on the client, then you'll get the same 3, 6, 42 order

Comment: @ironfist you need to create an array of objects instead of the object in backend to have them in the same order, otherwise in client side you will get the object keys numerically sorted when iterating them.

Comment: `I don't have access to backend` - so while this is a good answer, it can't possibly be implemented

Comment: You could take the original JSON string, search through it to find all id's in order, and then take the object and create a new array out of it, ordered by the id's you took earlier.

Comment: @ironfist I updated the answer to include the conversion to an array

Answer (score 0):

This is bound to have edge cases, but adding it because it works

If you are getting the data from the backend in the form of `JSON` then you can do the following

note: var json is a placeholder, as you haven't shown HOW you get your data

```js
var json = `{
    "6": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "John",
        "age": 31
    },
    "42": {
        "id": 42,
        "name": "Alex",
        "age": 25
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Tim",
        "age": 58
    }
}`;

var result = JSON.parse(json.replace(/\s?"(\d+)":/g, '"$1 ":'));
console.log(Object.keys(result));
```

Again, this is bound to fail, but I can't see any other way you can "fix" this on the client side - I thought JSON.parse "reviver" function would help, but it gets the properties in 3, 6, 42 order as well - so, no use at all